# Substituição de caracter Oracle

Tags: banco-de-dados, oracle

Tenho um campo na minha tabela com uma string da seguinte forma:

```
80,82,45,80,82,79,88,73,77,79,32,65,32
```

Quero substituir a vírgula (`,`) por vírgula entre aspas simples (`','`), para ficar:

```
80','82','45','80','82','79','88','73','77','79','32','65','32
```

Estou tentando da seguinte forma:

```
SELECT REPLACE(CAMPO,',','','') 
FROM TABELA;
```

Porém me retorna:

> ORA-00939: muitos argumentos para a função.

Alguém tem alguma sugestão sobre como fazer?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Faltou umas aspas nos parâmetros do replace, ele esta interpretando como tivesse 4 parâmetros, os dois últimos sendo '', a sintaxe correta seria:

```
SELECT REPLACE('80,82,45,80,82,79,88,73,77,79,32,65,32',',',''',''') FROM dual
```

Comment: Cara, deu certo. Obrigado!